# In node.js why does passport session stop formidable from triggering 'file' events?

Tags: node.js, formidable, passport.js

In my app I am only using

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

and not

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

so that I can manually parse file uploads. It seems that this line

```
app.use(passport.session());
```

stops formidable from triggering file events:

```
form.on('file', function(name, file) {
  //never called
});
```

How can I use passport session and not clash with formidable file event?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like they've added a way to fix this. Using `app.use(passport.session({pauseStream:  true}));` instead will prevent async deserializations from breaking some middleware.

Source: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/pull/106

Answer (score 0):

The `passport.session()` method calls your `passport.deserializeUser()`, which itself usually makes a database call to fetch the user. This database call delays the execution of code that starts listening to the incoming data. That is, the data arrives while nobody is listening for it.